# How to solve bitwise inequalities?

Tags: bitwise-xor

Given two integers L and R. Let’s define XR=L⊕(L+1)⊕(L+2)⊕(L+3)⊕...⊕R (⊕ is bitwise XOR) Is there any integer M such that, (XR⊕M) < XR where L≤M≤R?

Constraint:
1≤ L ≤ R ≤ 10^16

Limits:
1s, 512 MB

I know how to find XR. But how to find M?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you, I've solved the problem. I'll take care of all the stuff next time.